# Using Stored Function with C API & Prepared Statements

Tags: mysql, c, prepared-statement, mysql-connector

I am attempting to use a stored function with a prepared statement but not having any success.

MySQL prepares the statement but then does not execute it, no error is given, it just silently fails.

This is the *function:

```
drop function if exists lineDistanceC;
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION lineDistanceC (la1 DOUBLE, lo1 DOUBLE, la2 DOUBLE, lo2 DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE 
BEGIN 
SET @r = 6371;
SET @lat1 = RADIANS(la1);
SET @lon1 = RADIANS(lo1);
SET @lat2 = RADIANS(la2);
SET @lon2 = RADIANS(lo2);
SET @x = (@lon2-@lon1) * COS((@lat1+@lat2)/2);
SET @y = (@lat2 - @lat1);
RETURN (SQRT((@x*@x) + (@y*@y)) * @r);
END
//
delimiter ;
```

It works on the command line as expected, and substituting a hard coded double in the SELECT statement then allows it to work as expected, so the surrounding code is fine as well.

I have enabled CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS as a MySQL connect parameter, I suspect that it only relates to CALLing procedures, but it was a straw worth clutching.

The statement is prepared using:

```
strcpy (sqlStr, "SELECT lineDistanceC(Y(pnt),X(pnt), ?, ?) FROM mytable");
MYSQL_STMT *statement;
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(statement, sqlStr, strlen(sqlStr))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:mysql_stmt_prepare() failed. Error:%s\nsql:%s\n", mysql_stmt_error(statement), sqlStr);
}
```

Followed by the required bind statements for the parameters and the results, then executed using:

```
if (mysql_stmt_execute(statement)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mysql_stmt_execute(), failed. Error:%s\n", mysql_stmt_error(statement));
}
```

As mentioned earlier if the function in the above SELECT statement is replaced by a hard code float (Eg. SELECT 2.3 .....) then it returns the hard coded number as expected.

In reality the prepared statement code is inserted using macros, there are many hundreds of statements working as required so the preparation, binding or execution syntax is not the issue (and if it is incorrect above then it is my translation from the macros that is wrong) unless it needs to be different for use with functions.

These are the log entries when one of the inputs is bound as the output:

```
Prepare SELECT ? FROM mytable
Execute SELECT 51.36000061035156 FROM mytable
```

The is the log entry when I attempt to use the function:

```
Prepare SELECT lineDistanceC(latitude, longitude, ?, ?) FROM mytable;
```

As mentioned above, it silently fails without executing the statement, no errors in the log  or elsewhere.

Any clues would be appreciated.

*To give credit where it is due, this function was derived from a formula [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: Can you include an example of how you call it? Both when it works and doesn't?

Comment: @ethrbunny Updated as requested

Comment: What do you get if you try returning some of the parameters? (IE skip the code and just check that your inputs are rational)

Comment: @ethrbunny Further details added

Comment: So you can verify that each of your parameters is getting entered properly? What is the 'log entry'?  Can you post the code that creates and executes the prepared statement?

Comment: @ethrbunny Yes, the parameters are correctly entered and bound. The first log entries (from mysqld.general.log) above show what would normally be used as an input parameter being used also as an output thus proving beyond doubt that it is correct. The code for creating and binding the new debugging statements is the same as for the real statements.

Comment: where are you calling 'mysql_stmt_init'?

Comment: @ethrbunny Just before the prepare statement. The prepared statement syntax is absolutely, definitely without a doubt okay. As I said earlier I use macros for it and they are used literally hundreds of times without a problem. The issue is NOT with the prepared statements unless some special provision needs making for user defined functions.

Comment: Have you tried preparing and executing a call to the stored function with literal (non-parameterised) arguments, from C?  Have you tried preparing and executing a call to the stored function with parameterised arguments from the MySQL command line tool?

Answer (score 4):

I hacked up a quick example to test and wasn't able to reproduce your issue on MySql 5.1.66.  Seeing the `Prepare` statement in your log indicates that the query is syntactically correct and that the server is now ready to accept the parameters.  If you fail to correctly bind input parameters, you won't see the `Query` log message.

You should probably verify again that your bind macros are producing the correct C code.  The following snippet shows a functioning set of API calls which might give you some further ideas to help debugging.  The only change I made to your function as to add the [DETERMINISTIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) clause to avoid errors with binary logging on my system.

Starting with a table like this:

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     3 |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then executing the following query gives these results:

```
mysql> SELECT lineDistanceC(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, value) FROM mytable;
+-------------------------------------+
| lineDistanceC(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, value) |
+-------------------------------------+
|                    248.609129229989 |
|                    222.389853289118 |
|                    248.609129229989 |
+-------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following C code attempts the same query, but using the MySql API.  Note that memory management and correct error checking has not been implemented.

```
/* mysql_test.c */

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <mysql.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char sqlStr[300];


    MYSQL *mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (mysql == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:mysql_init() failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    const char* host = "localhost";
    const char* user = "root";
    const char* passwd = NULL;
    const char* db = "mysql_test";

    if (mysql_real_connect(mysql, host, user, passwd, db, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:mysql_real_connect() failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    MYSQL_STMT *statement = NULL;
    statement = mysql_stmt_init(mysql);
    if (statement == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:mysql_stmt_init() failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy (sqlStr, "SELECT lineDistanceC(1.0, 2.0, ?, value) FROM mytable");

    if (mysql_stmt_prepare(statement, sqlStr, strlen(sqlStr))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:mysql_stmt_prepare() failed. Error:%s\nsql:%s\n", mysql_stmt_error(statement), sqlStr);
        exit(1);
    }

    MYSQL_BIND input_bind[1];
    memset(input_bind, 0, sizeof(input_bind));
    float v1 = 3.0;
    unsigned long v1_len = sizeof(v1);

    input_bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT;
    input_bind[0].buffer = &v1;
    input_bind[0].buffer_length = sizeof(v1);
    input_bind[0].length = &v1_len;
    input_bind[0].is_null = (my_bool*)0;

    if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(statement, input_bind)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:mysql_stmt_bind_param failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_stmt_execute(statement)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mysql_stmt_execute(), failed. Error:%s\n", mysql_stmt_error(statement));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Fetch result set meta information */
    MYSQL_RES* prepare_meta_result = mysql_stmt_result_metadata(statement);
    if (!prepare_meta_result)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                " mysql_stmt_result_metadata(), \
                returned no meta information\n");
        fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(statement));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Get total columns in the query */
    int column_count= mysql_num_fields(prepare_meta_result);
    if (column_count != 1) /* validate column count */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, " invalid column count returned by MySQL\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Bind single result column, expected to be a double. */
    MYSQL_BIND result_bind[1];
    memset(result_bind, 0, sizeof(result_bind));

    my_bool result_is_null[1];
    double result_double;
    unsigned long result_len = 0;

    result_bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE;
    result_bind[0].buffer = &result_double;
    result_bind[0].buffer_length = sizeof(result_double);
    result_bind[0].length = &result_len;
    result_bind[0].is_null = &result_is_null[1];

    if (mysql_stmt_bind_result(statement, result_bind)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mysql_stmt_bind_Result(), failed. Error:%s\n", mysql_stmt_error(statement));
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!mysql_stmt_fetch(statement)) {
        printf("%.12f\n", result_double);
    }

}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -o mysql_test mysql_test.c -lmysqlclient
```

Here's the output:

```
248.609129229989
222.389853289118
248.609129229989
```

This matches the output of the statement executed using the mysql command line client.

You should be able to compile and run this on your system to determine if the problem is with your usage of the API or some other problem.

Comment: @blankabout Did you try compiling and running the code in my answer?  I'd be interested to know if you solved the problem and the solution.